# Symfony, default use app.php

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to put online a Symfony Project on a DEbian and i have a problem.

In my host I have DocumentRoot `/var/www/myproject/web/`, and when I display the website on my browser, I just have a list of files (the web folder in Symfony)

I want to use by default the app.php, how can I do that ?

Comment: Are you sure you also upload .htaccess file?

Comment: Yes i have the htaccess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This case should be handled by `.htaccess` file which you should have in your `web` directory. To make this work you need to have apache `mod_rewrite` enabled and have a proper configuration of your `VirtualHost`: you need to have `AllowOverride All` in your `Directory` directive

BTW: Your server shows list of files in directory - this is considered to be dangerous in production server. Disable it by `Options -Indexes` in your `VirtualHost` configuration.

So your `VirtualHost` configuration should have (this is apache 2.4 conf):

```
<Directory /path/to/your/web/>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Oh yeah thanks ! And is there a way to don't display the app.php in the url ?

Comment: with proper configuration it should work without `app.php` also

Comment: Yeah, but when i display the website, i am redirected to app.php

Comment: do you have apache's `mod_rewrite` enabled?

Comment: Oh, it's ok now.. don't know why ^^ Thanks !